# xcode regular search/replace bug?

Tags: xcode, replace, expression

I am attempting to refactor some old code, and want to replace `[self.* release];` with `self.* = nil;` where `*` is some property name.

I am using a regular expression search like `(\[self\.)(\w)+[\s](release\])` and for the replacement text I am using `self.\2 = nil`. This all goes fine (180 results, yay) but when I preview (or perform the replace), the result only copies the last letter of the \w token.

For example, `[self.property release];` would become `self.y = nil;`. Anyone know what is up here?

Thanks

Comment: When I read regex documentation, I always feel like [this](http://thejoysofcode.tumblr.com/post/35331265331/when-i-am-forced-to-read-regex-documentation)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is little bit old, but I wanted this and solved it like below

```
(\[self\.)(.*)( release\])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
`(\[self\.)(\w)*[\s](release\])`